# Difference between in-line variable inclusion within string or addition of variable after string?

Tags: swift, string, xcode, performance, output

I don't really know the terminology for this, so I'm sorry if the title is confusing.
But my question is, what is the difference between the below code, and which of the two methods is the better, more efficient one?

```
var a = "World"
print("Hello \(a)")
```

OR

```
var a = "World"
print("Hello " + a)
```

Comment: In this simple case there's no difference, but if you need to build a more complex string, using string interpolation (this is the term) is better.

Comment: Terms are interpolation and concatenation. there is also `["Hello", b].joined(separator: " ")` which is very useful. While interpolation is easier to use, concatenation is much faster. the join is fast too (and easy to use). But unless you're doing crazy string manipulations I would use interpolation as its easier to see what is going on which leads to less bugs.